# ConstraintLayout together with RecyclerVIew (ListAdapter) appears to use HUGE amounts of memory (up to 1GB) when loading a list with +6000 items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory

I'm building a simple FileExplorer for my app, and using Coroutines I get the files in a given path, and while displaying them, there are spikes in memory usage. I show the profiler tool tabs at the bottom of the post.
My best guess is that the adapter is creating a viewholder for every single item on the list and that is using all the memory of the app and the device itself.

Edit: by using RelativeLayout instead of ConstraintLayout, it decreased the memory usage by a factor of 3, and it takes a few seconds for the list to be displayed.

Quick summary of the content:

0 - function that gets the contents in the path

1 - OutOfMemoryException message on the Run console of AndroidStudio

2 - Garbage collector log

3 - Code snippet that the OOM error points to

4 - Where the above code snippet is called

5 - ViewHolder code

6 - Profiler screenshot showing overview of biggest spike (over 1GB)

7 - DialogFragment layout file where the RecyclerView is declared

8 - the Row

9 - Tabs from the profiler tool showing ConstraintLayout calls and onMeasure and related functions

10 - RecyclerView and ConstraintLayout versions

*the function that actually gets the files*

```
private fun getFilesOnPath(path : String, showHiddenFiles : Boolean = false, onlyFolders : Boolean = false) : List<File> {
    val file = File(path)

    var listOfFiles = listOf<File>()

    try {
        listOfFiles = file.listFiles()
             .filter { showHiddenFiles || !it.name.startsWith(".") }
             .filter { !onlyFolders || it.isDirectory }.toList()
    } catch (exception : IllegalStateException) {
        Timber.tag(LOG_TAG).e("${exception.message} \n ${exception.cause}")
    } finally {
         return listOfFiles
    }

}
```

"beforeMain" and "afterMain" are there for when I implement a ProgressBar and to show them at appropriate times

I notice that on folders with less files the UI doesn't lag until the list of files is loaded, but when clicking on this particularly large WhatsApp folder, the app will run out of memory with this appearing on the console (PS: This error has nothing to do with the list of items, it is loaded and filtered just fine):

```
at java.lang.Throwable.nativeFillInStackTrace(Native method)
        at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:775)
        at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:258)
        at java.lang.Error.<init>(Error.java:70)
        at java.lang.VirtualMachineError.<init>(VirtualMachineError.java:53)
        at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>(OutOfMemoryError.java:58)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:829)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:531)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:461)
        at goldengentleman.goldennotebook.adapters.FileExplorerAdapter$FilesViewHolder$Companion.from(FileExplorerAdapter.kt:153)
        at goldengentleman.goldennotebook.adapters.FileExplorerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FileExplorerAdapter.kt:52)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7201)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6332)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6216)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6212)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2314)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4215)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3615)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24967)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:736)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:399)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:105)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:232)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:113)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1480)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1555)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7134)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7134)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7134)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:992)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24967)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3270)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2300)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1861)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8478)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

And there are the obvious Garbage Collector logs on the Console:

```
I/nnotebook.debu: Clamp target GC heap from 216MB to 192MB
    Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 192MB/192MB, paused 145us total 826.488ms
```

The problem is probably the ridiculosly large list with actually 6000 items on it, but the error makes it seem like the problem is on the Adapter, this is where the console points to:

```
companion object {
     fun from(parent : ViewGroup) : FilesViewHolder = FilesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_file_explorer_file, parent, false))
}
```

and where it's calling the above function:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent : ViewGroup, viewType : Int) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder = when (viewType) {
        MODE_FOLDERS -> FoldersViewHolder.from(parent)
        MODE_FILES -> FilesViewHolder.from(parent)
        else -> FilesViewHolder.from(parent)
    }
```

Edit:
Here is the ViewHolder class (PS: Don't try to understand the onClick and onClickListeners, it's just logic for multiselection):

```
    class FilesViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val fileName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_name_textView)
        private val fileIcon : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_icon_imageView)
        private val fileFormat : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_format_textView)
        private val fileSize : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_size_textView)
        private val fileTimeCreated : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_created_textView)
        private val root : ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.root)

        fun bind(item : FileModel, context : Context, adapter : FileExplorerAdapter) {

            if (item.fileType == FileType.FOLDER) {
                fileName.text = item.name
                fileIcon.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.folder_icon))
                fileSize.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                fileTimeCreated.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                fileFormat.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_square)
            } else {
                fileSize.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                fileTimeCreated.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                fileFormat.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                fileName.text = item.name
                fileFormat.text = item.extension
                fileSize.text = item.sizeInMB
                fileTimeCreated.text = Time.convertUnixToDateTime(item.timeCreated)
                val ext = item.extension
                fileIcon.apply {
                    setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(
                        if (item.fileType == FileType.FOLDER) R.drawable.folder_icon
                        else if (ext == "pdf") R.drawable.pdf_box
                        else if (ext == "doc" || ext == "docx") R.drawable.file_word
                        else if (ext == "mp3" || ext == "3gp") R.drawable.music
                        else if (ext == "mp4" || ext == "webm") R.drawable.video
                        else if (ext == "jpg" || ext == "png") R.drawable.image
                        else R.drawable.file))
                }
                if (item in adapter.selectedFiles) {
                    root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_square_selected)
                } else {
                    root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_square)
                }
            }

            root.setOnClickListener {
               // Does multi-selection stuff like changing the rows background
            }

            root.setOnLongClickListener {
                // does the same as the above onClickListener
                true
            }

        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent : ViewGroup) : FilesViewHolder = FilesViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_file_explorer_file, parent, false))
        }
    }
```

And this is the Profiler during its biggest spike:

[image: Ridiculously large spike in memory usage]

This js where the recyclerView is declared in the dialogfragment layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:background = "@drawable/dialog_fullscreen_background">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id = "@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:elevation = "12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id = "@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background = "?attr/toolbar_bottom_nav_color"
            android:paddingStart = "6dp"
            android:paddingEnd = "16dp"
            android:elevation = "@dimen/toolbar_nav_elevation"
            app:subtitleTextColor = "?attr/secondary_text_color"
            app:titleTextColor = "?attr/primary_text_color"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation = "0dp"
            app:navigationIcon = "@drawable/close_x"
            tools:title = "@string/internal_storage" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id = "@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "0dp"
        app:layoutManager = "androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf = "@+id/_constraintLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf = "@+id/appBarLayout"
        tools:listitem = "@layout/row_file_explorer" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id = "@+id/_constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "64dp"
        android:background = "?attr/toolbar_bottom_nav_color"
        android:elevation = "@dimen/toolbar_nav_elevation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias = "0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent">

        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/save_button"
            style = "@style/dialogButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd = "8dp"
            android:text = "@string/save"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent" />

        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/cancel_button"
            style = "@style/dialogButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd = "8dp"
            android:text = "@string/cancel"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf = "@+id/save_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id = "@+id/root"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "75dp"
    android:background = "@drawable/border_square"
    android:foreground = "@drawable/custom_ripple_no_border">

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/file_name_textView"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart = "16dp"
        android:ellipsize = "start"
        android:singleLine = "true"
        android:textColor = "?attr/primary_text_color"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "@+id/file_icon_imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf = "@+id/file_icon_imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "@+id/file_icon_imageView"
        tools:text = "File file file" />

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/file_icon_imageView"
        android:layout_width = "50dp"
        android:layout_height = "50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart = "16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop = "16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "16dp"
        android:tint = "?attr/primary_text_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
        app:srcCompat = "@drawable/folder_icon"
        tools:ignore = "ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/file_format_textView"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd = "8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "8dp"
        android:textColor = "?attr/secondary_text_color"
        android:textSize = "12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
        tools:text = "Image File" />

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/file_size_textView"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop = "8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd = "8dp"
        android:textColor = "?attr/secondary_text_color"
        android:textSize = "12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
        tools:text = "100KB" />

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/time_created_textView"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop = "4dp"
        android:textColor = "?attr/secondary_text_color"
        android:textSize = "12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "@+id/file_name_textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf = "@+id/file_name_textView"
        tools:text = "25/08/2000" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

Now, for the profiler tool tabs.
It shows A LOT of stuff that appears to be related to ConstraintLayout, such as:

[image: AppHeap]

[image: Biggest class in ShallowSize and TotalCount]

and many others also basically shows the same, many many calls to onMeasure and related ui functions.

RecyclerView and ConstraintLayout versions on app/buildgradle

```
// ConstraintLayout
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta6'

// RecyclerView
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

Comment: If you comment out the filesOnPath function and just return an empty list, do you still get the issue?

Comment: I do not, because any other folder will open fine, it's just these behemoths ones.

Comment: Can you attach the layout file where recyclerview is declared?

Comment: Done. Also added the row's layout file

Comment: Are you using ListAdapter? And what does `FileModel.equals()` look like? ListAdapter does comparisons of the list items when the data changes, which could be a problem if `FileModel.equals()` is deeply comparing actual file contents.

Comment: ListAdapter yes, cause i found it's the easiest to work with. FileModel is a kotlin data class with fields such as: Name, path, file type (an enum which differenciates a file from a folder), size (formatted string from file.length()),  extension (string with what is after the . in the path), and subfiles (int counter of files inside a folder, returned by File().listFiles()). will attach the file model as soon as i can

Comment: I doubt that it's anything to do with the items, but everything to do with the RecyclerView. I am going to refactor my question to express that

Comment: What's the ConstraintLayout library version?

Comment: @YuriyMysochenko latest beta and the RecyclerView is the latest alpha. Added both to the post, at the bottom (and also added a summary because holy moly it's a big post)

Comment: @Sir latest beta is 7. Check this changelog, they have fixed many issues regarding both recyclerView and memory leaks: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/06/constraintlayout-200-beta-7.html

Comment: @YuriyMysochenko removing ConstraintLayout altogether and using RelativeLayout reduced the memory usage by A LOT, never going above 400MB, and after a few minutes it actually did load the folder, with it open and no scrolling it is at 300MB flat.

Comment: You can use Paging library, to only load portions of your list at a time

Comment: @Zain DUDE, replacing CL with RelativeLayout completely solved all my problems, all items load in a few seconds, so Constraintlayout was the reason for the memory leak. Didn't manage to test updating the CL version, will test it and then update my post or even answer it if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the "bug" was in the ConstraintLayout lib the whole time. The version I had:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta6'
```

Apparently had a memory leak problem of sorts that the 2.0.0-beta7 version solved. Unfortunatelly my AndroidStudio didn't show me that there even was an update at all.
Huge thanks to @YuriyMysochenko for spotting it, and for the people that tried to help me!